# Pyinstaller with matplotlib (conda environment)

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an executable file for my simple plot script.
Basically, print command runs but the plot does not show anything and just suddenly exits.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
print ("DO TEST")
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()

fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

The environment I am using was created via anaconda using:
`conda create -n test_env -c conda-forge python=3.7 matplotlib numpy pandas opencv pyinstaller pyqt`

Running the code via terminal or IDE using the created env is successful.

Comment: Did you use `--onefile` with pyinstaller?

Comment: Yes, I did. Both: with and without did not work for me

Comment: With `--onefile` it could be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63265728/4593433 Otherwise you can try other suggestions from there.

Comment: Thank you for the help but their solutions did not work for me.