# Cannot import matplotlib in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

Trying to import matplotlib and running the file generated by `pyinstaller test.py` results in the error:

```
Fatal Python error: _PyInterpreterState_Get(): no current thread state
Python runtime state: unknown
```

Importing any other package works fine when creating a .exe file from a .py file with Pyinstaller, only matplotlib gives the error. The error can be reproduced by simply creating a .py file with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

From pipdeptree:

```
pyinstaller==4.5.1
  - altgraph [required: Any, installed: 0.17.2]
  - pefile [required: >=2017.8.1, installed: 2021.9.3]
    - future [required: Any, installed: 0.18.2]
  - pyinstaller-hooks-contrib [required: >=2020.6, installed: 2021.4]
  - pywin32-ctypes [required: >=0.2.0, installed: 0.2.0]
  - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 59.5.0]

- matplotlib [required: >=3, installed: 3.5.0]
  - cycler [required: >=0.10, installed: 0.11.0]
  - fonttools [required: >=4.22.0, installed: 4.28.3]
  - kiwisolver [required: >=1.0.1, installed: 1.3.2]
  - numpy [required: >=1.17, installed: 1.21.4]
  - packaging [required: >=20.0, installed: 21.3]
    - pyparsing [required: >=2.0.2,!=3.0.5, installed: 3.0.6]
  - pillow [required: >=6.2.0, installed: 8.4.0]
  - pyparsing [required: >=2.2.1, installed: 3.0.6]
  - python-dateutil [required: >=2.7, installed: 2.8.2]
    - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
  - setuptools-scm [required: >=4, installed: 6.3.2]
    - packaging [required: >=20.0, installed: 21.3]
      - pyparsing [required: >=2.0.2,!=3.0.5, installed: 3.0.6]
    - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 59.5.0]
    - tomli [required: >=1.0.0, installed: 1.2.2]
```

I have tried different versions of matplotlib but the error remains. I also don't really know which versions I should try. Importing matplotlib used to work before some time ago, but I don't know what matplotlib version (or any of the dependencies' version) I was using at the time.
I am on Windows, using a Virtual Environment and build the bootloader according to https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bootloader-building.html

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by going down to specifically matplotlib==3.2.2 as suggested here [How to use pyinstaller with matplotlib in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163027/how-to-use-pyinstaller-with-matplotlib-in-use) for another problem